# Matching Regular Expression for URLS in JavaScript Produces null

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regular expression which I have validated:

```
"(http|ftp|https)://([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?"
```

[image]

I have the following Javascript code to find regular expressions:

```
var cTextVal = "This URL should match http://google.com";
var regEx = "(http|ftp|https)://([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?"


var matches = cTextVal.match(regEx);
alert(matches); // This produces null
```

How do I find the string that matches this regular expression in JavaScript?

**Update Based on Comments:**

This crashes my code:

```
var regEx = /(http|ftp|https)://([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?/g
```

This produces null:

```
var regEx = "/(http|ftp|https)://([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?/g"
```

Comment: You need to use `/yourRegex/`, not `"yourRegex"`, otherwise you need to escape the backslashes.

Comment: or new RegExp .... but then escaping the \'s is a pain in that case

Comment: It would be at `matches[0]` for the entire match if there was one, which there is not based on the `null` result.

Comment: I am very confused about that. Could someone post what the regEx variable should look like as it should be in my code. I am not good with regular expressions.

Comment: Just replace the opening `"` by `/` and the closing `"` by `/g` — exactly as shown in your screenshot.

Comment: var regEx = /(http|ftp|https)://([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?/g crashes my code

Comment: because u didnt backslash slashes

Comment: just a note u can compress this part `(http|ftp|https)` into `(https?|ftp)` ;)

Comment: Note that the `//` has _red underlines_ in the regex debugger. This _could_ mean an error.

Comment: It all makes sense now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape forward slashes before second capture group

```js
var regEx = /(http|ftp|https):\/\/([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?/;

var cTextVal = "This URL should match http://google.com";

var matches = cTextVal.match(regEx).shift();

console.log(matches);
```